# Why are separate .jsx file not being included when using react in my metor.js app

Tags: node.js, meteor, reactjs, flow-router, meteor-react

I have been working on a meteor.js and react.js app using meteor-react and flow-router.

I Started with a structure like this:

- client

  - components

    - register.jsx
  - layouts

    - header.jsx
    - footer.jsx
  - lib

    - router.jsx
      main.html
      main.jsx

in my router.jsx file I cal the RegisterForm class from the register.jsx file

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
    action() {
        ReactLayout.render(MainLayout, { content: <RegistrationForm /> });
    }
```

});

This works well as long as all my component classes are in the register.jsx file but as my project is getting bigger, instead of putting all classes in a single file I want to split register.jsx into separate .jsx files.

For example, I have a class called VerifiedInput which contains extra functionality for custom validation of input fields.  If I include this class in the same register.jsx I can call it in the render function of my RegisterForm Class,

```
VerifiedInput = React.createClass({
    ....
});

RegistrationForm = React.createClass({
   ....    
   render : function(){
       return(
           <VerifiedInput />
        )
    }
});
```

but if I move the VerifiedInput class into a separate file so my component folder structure changes to :

```
- components
   - register.jsx
   - validinput.jsx
```

then I get an error: **ReferenceError: VerifiedInput is not defined**

Which seems to suggest the .jsx file is not being included.

As I undertand it meteor should include files in the client folder automatically and its not possible to use **require()** Meteor.js

How do I make sure react classes in separate files are included?

Comment: did you remember to export the component?

Comment: this should work, I've personally tried it and it does, your code looks correct :/

Comment: You don't need to export the component in Meteor @DominicTobias I think you are right.  I cut down the example to the most minimal form and it is working.  It seems strange that includes break without reason if there is an error.

Comment: Yep that doesn't sound like very good error handling on their part!